# The data on Apple watch send to firebase

Tags: firebase, watchos, watchos-4

I want to send the acceleration data which is retrieved from Apple Watch to Cloud Storage for Firebase.

However, Firebase is not support watchOS.

Should I have sent the acceleration data to the storage via iPhone?

Please teach me a better method.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could send the data to the Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore using the REST Service. By implementing a Firebase node.js cloud function which triggers on Data Writes you could copy the data to Cloud Storage. 
Anyway for your purpose it seems to be a better solution to work with the super fast Realtime Database instead of the slow storage.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I want to accumulate the data, so I don't have to make fast Realtime Database.
Anyway, although firebase does not support watchos, can I implement firevase node.js cloud function?
I have no idea to implement.
Could you tell me how to.